# C# Interface Problem

Tags: c#, interface

For some reason, I am having issues with Interfaces. I know a 100 examples have been posted but apparently I'm not smart enough to figure it out...

I have the following interface:

```
namespace DocStore.Interfaces
{
  public interface IResetCategoryControl
  {
    string CategoryToAdd { set; }
  }
}
```

I want to set CategoryToAdd to a value.

Here is my class that I want to set it in and what I have so far:

```
  public partial class AddDocumentsDialog : IResetCategoryControl

    public string CategoryToAdd
    {
      set
      {
        IResetCategoryControl() ireset = new IResetCategoryControl();
        ireset.CategoryToAdd = value;       
      }
    }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong in the AddDocumentDialog class? I can't get that part to work.

Thank you!

Eroc

Comment: What problem are you having? What's the error message?

Comment: How is this not working?  If the `AddDocumentsDialog` class is not in the same namespace then you need to qualify the interface name where it is used eg. `DocStore.Interfaces.IResetCategoryControl`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? the setter doesn't make a lot of sense as it is now...

Comment: Maybe add more information regarding expected behavior and what you're trying to accomplish. It's hard to determine what you would like to do from your example. You implemented CategoryToAdd  correctly (even though you have some issues inside the set as mentioned in the answers below). Interfaces are code contracts that reinforce uniformity for better "impedance matching". What isn't working?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I responded in the post that I accepted! I got it working!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following line is the problematic one:

```
IResetCategoryControl() ireset = new IResetCategoryControl();
```

First, you need to get rid of first parenthesis:

```
IResetCategoryControl ireset = new IResetCategoryControl();
```

Next, you cannot instantiate an interface. Interface is only a signature which has to be implemented by a concrete class.

If you are looking at some other people's code, right click on IResetCategoryControl and select "Find all references" to search if this interface has already been implemented in some class.

For example, you may find:

```
class SomeResetCatControl : IResetCategoryControl 
{

}
```

On the other hand, it looks like you only need to set an internal private field in your setter method. You should do it like this in that case:

```
public partial class AddDocumentsDialog : IResetCategoryControl
{
   private string _categoryToAdd = "";
   public string CategoryToAdd
   {
     set
     {
        _categoryToAdd = value;
     }
   }
}
```

But as others have already pointed out, using a write-only property is very unusual, and indicates wrong design.

Comment: This was what I was looking for but like you said, it was wrong. Everyone's post made me rethink how I was doing this and I reworked it and it is working much smoother now.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do in your setter...but the following line is causing you problems:

```
IResetCategoryControl() ireset = new IResetCategoryControl();
```

First of all, you don't use parenthesis when declaring the type of a variable. Second of all, you can't directly instantiate an instance of an Interface. To make that statement valid it would have to be something along the lines of:

```
IResetCategoryControl iReset = new SomeConcreteResetCategoryControl();
```

**There is a bigger issue though:**

Theoretically, your class is implementing the interface and the interface specifies that you need a property called `CategoryToAdd` with a public setter. That property should be setting the value on your class...not a new instance of another class.

I would expect the code to look something like:

```
public partial class AddDocumentsDialog : IResetCategoryControl
{
    private string categoryToAdd;

    public string CategoryToAdd
    {
        set
        {
            // do some logic to validate the value
            categoryToAdd = value;
        }
    }
}
```

You might also want to re-think your interface design as set only properties are typically discouraged (in favor of using a method, since a set only property indicates some amount of logic being executed and the value being only used internally by the class rather than accessed by the consumer again).

Answer (score 10):

You can't instantiate an interface; it is merely a contract and not an object itself.  You need to figure out what the contract means and have AddDocumentsDialog implement that contract, doing whatever it is supposed to do when CategoryToAdd is set.

On a side note, set-only properties are discouraged.  It's better to use a method.

Comment: +1 for the set-only remark. That is a rather unusual way to use properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can't instantiate an interface:

```
IResetCategoryControl() ireset = new IResetCategoryControl();
```

After the `new` keyword you must use an object that implements that interface.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't valid C# -- remove the first pair of `()`:

```
IResetCategoryControl() ireset = new IResetCategoryControl();
```

**Edit:** It's still not valid C#. You can't instantiate an interface, only classes.

Answer (score 1):

ireset is only defined locally, within the set. You won't be able to access it anywhere else

Answer (score 1):

You can't instantiate an interface.  new IResetCategoryControl is never going to work.  AddDocumentsCatalog implements IResetCAtegoryControl with the string property CategoryToAdd.  Whatever computation you do to return CategoryToAdd is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, ireset is going out of scope as soon as you've set one of its properties.  I'm guessing that should probably be a member variable...

I'm making the assumption the 'IResetCategoryControl()' type declaration is a typo, but if not, that's also an issue.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, as it is correct.  I missed the instantiating an interface, but there was so much wrong there it was hard to know where to look...